# MySQL: DATE_FORMAT Not Working on %m/%d/%Y but Works on %Y/%m/%d

Tags: mysql

When I execute this query:

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_FORMAT('2021/09/17 12:00:00 AM', "%Y/%m/%d %h:%i:%s %p"))
```

This is the result:

**9/17/2021**

But, when I put %Y on last, and execute this query:

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_FORMAT('09/17/2021 12:00:00 AM', "%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p"))
```

This is the result:

**(NULL)**

I am expecting to get the result also as **9/17/2021**. How can I achieve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are using date_format where you should be using str_to_date.  date_format produces a formatted string from a date or datetime.  str_to_date does the opposite, parsing a formatted string and returning the date or datetime.

Comment: Whoah thank you so much, @ysth! This is now resolved.